# Как отправлять данные из БД в Telegram Bot определенному пользователю

Tags: django, telegram-bot

**Должна быть админка (делаю на Django), пользователь добавляется в канале бота ему приходит его айди, админ вводит все данные в бд через админку или формы (обычный html шаблон)**

```
# Модель клиента 

class Client(models.Model):        
surname = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
fatname = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
phone = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
tgid = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)    # id клиента в канале бота

def __str__(self):
    fullname = self.surname + ' ' + self.name + ' ' + self.fatname
    return fullname
```

**Далее админ создает модель чека (оплата за учебу) и отправляет определенному клиенту в канале бота**

```
# Модель чека

class Check(models.Model):
client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
summary = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
summary_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
text_font = ImageFont.truetype('font.ttf', 200)  # шрифт
default_check_image = Image.open("default_check.jpg")
client_check_image = ImageDraw.Draw(default_check_image)

def save(self):
    self.client_check_image.text((0, 20), self.summary, (237, 230, 211), font=self.text_font)
    self.client_check_image.text((0, 30), self.summary_name, (237, 230, 211), font=self.text_font)
    self.client_check_image.save("client_check.jpg")
    # тут мы записываем суму чека цифрами и буквами поверх стандартного изображения чека
    # и сохраняем в новое которое должны отправить клиенту
```

**Я представляю так что после сохранения чек автоматически отправляется клиенту. И все тут я застрял что и как делать, как наладить работу бэкэнда на Django с телеграм ботом?
Или может мне нужна другая структура проекта без Django?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать POST функцию во views.py принять там параметры формы из request.POST и сохранить данные в Вашу модель. Пример работы с данными формы  [можно посмотреть здесь](http://learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-save-data-from-a-form-to-a-database-table-in-Django.php). По поводу работы с Телеграм ботом, советую библиотеку [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot). Там в репозитории есть папка examples где можно подглядеть примеры работы с ботом. Как сформировать токен бота можно найти на сайте Телеграм и в гугле. Про взаимодействие джанги с самим ботом я делаю команду в `/<app>/management/commands/run_bot.py` и там запускаю работу с ботом, исходя из документации к библиотеке. Здесь основной вопрос как передавать данные из Django в этот обработчик. Сходу не могу придумать как это правильнее осуществить, такой задачи у меня не возникало, но как вариант можно запустить из команды `run_bot.py` поток, который будет отслеживать изменения данных в БД. Надеюсь я ответил на все Ваши вопросы :)